# Obtener titulo de documento word con OLEOBJECT PB12.5

Tags: powershell

***No hay etiqueta para PB 12.5***
Tengo una función que revisa la ortografía de informes generados en PowerBuilder 12.5, usando unas funciones externas de windows.
mi problema se encuentra en la linea:

```
     ll_Hwnd = FindWindowA ( ls_Null, "Documento1 - Microsoft Word" ).
```

Hardcodee el titulo de la ventana para encontrarla más rápido.
si el usuario tiene una ventana de word abierta, jamas encontrará la ventana y no podré traerla al frente. por lo que mi pregunta es si hay alguna función en OleObject que me permita leer el titulo de la ventana. todos los ejemplos que encontré, guardan el documento asignándole un nombre y luego de usar el archivo, lo eliminan, pero me exigieron que no se guarde nada.

De funcionar, funciona, pero si alguien sabe otra forma de hacer que la ventana del corrector de word pase al frente, sería de mucha ayuda.

ejemplo:
global external functions:

```
     FUNCTION uInt FindWindowA(string szClass,  string szName) LIBRARY "user32.dll" alias for "FindWindowA;Ansi"
     FUNCTION uInt GetWindow(long hwnd,  long lnextwindow) LIBRARY "user32.dll"
     FUNCTION uInt GetWindowTextA(long hwnd,  ref string titleText, long nMaxCount) LIBRARY "user32.dll" alias for "GetWindowTextA;Ansi"
     FUNCTION boolean BringWindowToTop(long hwnd) LIBRARY "user32.dll"
     FUNCTION boolean SetForegroundWindow(long hwnd) LIBRARY "user32.dll"
     FUNCTION uInt SetActiveWindow(long hwnd) LIBRARY "user32.dll"
```

PB function:

```
     Long    ll_Hwnd  
     String  ls_Null 
     OLEObject  Ole_Word 
     LONG           ll_rc, lnStart, lnEnd
     ULONG      hActiveWindow, hData
     uint           HRTF
     ulong          CF_TEXT = 1

     p_rtf.SelectTextAll()
     if p_rtf.selectedlength() <= 0 then
        Messagebox("Atención","No hay texto a Revisar",Information!)
        return -1
     end if

     SetPointer(Hourglass!) 

     clipboard("")

     p_rtf.Copy()

     //* Obtener un identificador de la ventana activa.

     hActiveWindow = gu_ext_func.uf_GetActiveWindow()

     //* Abrir el portapapeles con una asociación a la 
     // Ventana activa.
     gu_ext_func.uf_OpenClipboard (hActiveWindow)

     // Registro RTF como formato de portapapeles válido.
     HRTF = gu_ext_func.uf_RegisterClipboardFormatA("Rich Text Format")

     // Obtener datos colocados en el portapapeles
     // En formato de texto.

     hData = gu_ext_func.uf_GetClipboardData (CF_TEXT)

     // Re-enviar el mismo bloque de memoria en el portapapeles
     gu_ext_func.uf_SetClipboardData (HRTF, hData)
     gu_ext_func.uf_CloseClipboard ()

     ole_Word = CREATE OleObject
     ll_rc =Ole_Word.ConnectToNewObject( 'Word.Application' )

     if ll_rc <> 0 THEN 
     destroy ole_Word
     RETURN -1
     end if 

     //Si se pudo crear el Word se crea y muestra el Documento 
     ole_Word.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     ole_Word.Application.Visible = True
     ole_Word.Application.WindowState = 2
     ole_Word.Documents.Add() 
     ole_Word.Selection.Paste()

     SetNull (ls_Null)
     // busco la ventana
     ll_Hwnd = FindWindowA ( ls_Null, "Documento1 - Microsoft Word" ) 
     // una vez lo tengo, lo mando al frente
     SetForegroundWindow((ll_Hwnd))
     SetActiveWindow(ll_Hwnd)
     BringWindowToTop(ll_Hwnd)

     ole_Word.ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling()
     lnStart = ole_Word.ActiveDocument.Content.Start
     lnEnd = ole_Word.ActiveDocument.Content.End
     ole_Word.ActiveDocument.Range(lnStart, lnEnd).Select

     gu_ext_func.uf_EmptyClipboard()
     ole_Word.Selection.Copy()
     p_rtf.Paste()

     ole_Word.ActiveDocument.Close( False )
     ole_Word.Application.Quit
     ole_Word.DisconnectObject()
     Destroy ole_Word
```